# How can I create a .app file to open DMG files with, to run AppleScript with that file as input?

Tags: macos, applescript

What I ultimately want to do is have a .app that I can open DMG files with. When the DMG file is opened the app, it opens the DMG in a new Finder tab and then shows the Toolbar in Finder after half a second. AppleScript for the later would look like this:

```
delay 0.5
tell application "Finder"
      tell the front window to set toolbar visible to true
end tell
```

I tried looking up how to open a DMG file in a new Finder Tab with AppleScript but didn't find a solution. If I end up not finding one, then I'll see if I can do so with a Terminal command and then do it in AS with `do shell script`.  For the file input, I tested this code based off what I found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406656/433365) but it doesn't work, it just creates a copy of the DMG:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if input is {} then
        set inputFile1 to ¬
            quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
            (choose file with prompt "Please select a file to process:")
    else
        set inputFile1 to quoted form of ¬
            (POSIX path of first item of input)
    end if
    display dialog inputFile1
    
end run
```

I did a bunch of googling as well for how to do so but I found nothing. What I can do to end up with an AppleScript that does everything I described?

Comment: Are you talking about opening a _mounted_ disk image in a tab?  Note that the Finder doesn’t have any terminology for tabs (other than the preference).

Comment: OK, but at least I want it to open the DMG file in Finder and then run whatever AppleScript (in this case the command to show the toolbar in Finder). I have `Finder > Settings > General > Open folders in new tabs` checked as well as `View > Show tab tab`. When I run open /path/tofolder in Terminal, and when I do `open ("/path/to/folder/" as POSIX file` under a `tell application "Finder"` block in AppleScript, it will open folders in a new tab if the Finder window is minimized. If it isn't then it will open it in a new window (which is fine).

Comment: I would open the dmg with `hdiutil` which seems to open the image into a standard window: `set runDMG to POSIX path of (choose file); do shell script "/usr/bin/hdiutil attach " & runDMG`. Replace `;` with return. You probably won't need to run the toolbar script.

Comment: @Mockman I'm not getting it working, can you post it as answer with exact formatting of the AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

I would open the dmg with hdiutil which seems to open the image into a standard window:

```
set runDMG to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose file)
do shell script "/usr/bin/hdiutil attach " & runDMG
```

Basically, you get the posix path of your dmg file and feed it to `hdiutil attach`. The disk image will open and —for me at least— consistently opens in a default finder window (i.e. same size as other windows, list view, sidebar visible, toolbar visible).

I should add that typically when I double-click on a dmg, it opens in a 'drag to applications folder' window which is icon view and shows only the app and the applications folder.

Separately, this code seems to work with bringing the disk image's folder to the front window.

```
tell application "Finder"
    
    parent of startup disk
    --> computer container of application "Finder"
    
    open computer container
    set target of window 1 to (last item of window 1 as alias)
    --> disk "Key Codes" of application "Finder"
    
end tell
```

There are (at least on my Sierra mac), three items in the 'computer' folder: 'Network', 'Remote Disc', the startup volume. When you open a dmg, the virtual appears here as a 'removable'. I've found that when you get a list of folders in the computer container, the removable is the last item in the list. I don't know if that ever changes, and I haven't played around with multiple disk images simultaneously but it provides a starting point for specifying the desired window if for some reason, it doesn't open automatically.

Comment: OK, so what exactly do I do with this AppleScript to use it?

Comment: Put the first one (with two lines) in an applescript and run it. Based on your question, I don't really know what you're trying to do beyond that.